# Alarma para fecha y hora concreta

Tags: c#

Chicos,alguien me puede ayudar... Explico lo que quiero hacer en visual studio

necesito una alarma para fecha y hora

Tengo 2 maskedTextBox uno quiero que sea para una fecha "/*/*/" el otro para una hora *:*:_ entonces necesito que al poner ahí por ejemplo 10/05/2021 13:50:00 que me lace una alarma en esa fecha y hora concreta

alguien me echa un cable? estoy siguiendo tutoriales pero no doy con la tecla , Gracias!

Comment: Podrías empezar por poner un timer que a cada segundo, verifique que la fecha y la hora son las que están en los _textbox_ y, si es así, que salte la alarma ... la versión 2.0 podría ser calcular cuánto tiempo queda hasta que salte la alarma y lanzar un únito tick del temporizador con el tiempo que acabas de calcular, por ejepmlo, si son las 10:00 y la alarma debe saltar a las 13:45 de ese mismo día, el tick del temporizador debe saltar tras 3 horas y 45 minutos

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa por favor [ask]., saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Te paso una app que genera una alarma a los 50 segundos de presoinar un botón
Puedes ir jugando con ella e ir cambiando esos segundos por la hora a la que deseas que salte la alarma.
Lo que hace la app, es abrir una segunda pantalla

Crea una clase AlarmReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //------< onReceive() >--------
        //this event triggers when alarm in Android happens
        //*open Wakeup Alarm Activity
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, PaginaAlarma.class);
        alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //open Activitiy
         context.startActivity(alarmIntent);
        //------</ onReceive() >--------
    }
}
```

Creas ahora la clase BackgroundSoundService que extienda de Service:

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "BackgroundSoundService";
    private AlarmManager alarmManager  = null;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent  = null;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBind()" );
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() , service started...");
    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onUnBind()");
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStop()");
    }
    public void onPause() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause()");
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() , service stopped...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLowMemory()");
    }
}
```

En el MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private AlarmManager alarmManager  = null;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent  = null;
    BackgroundSoundService miServicio = new BackgroundSoundService();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    //========< Buttons >===========
    public void btnOpenWakeup(View view) {
        Intent openWakeup = new Intent(this, PaginaAlarma.class);
        startActivity(openWakeup);
    }
    public void btnAlarmSetWakeup(View view) {
        //--------< btnAlarmSetWakeup() >--------
        setupAlarm();
        //--------</ btnAlarmSetWakeup() >--------
    }
    //========</ Buttons >===========


    //========< Methods >===========

    private void setupAlarm() {
        //--------< setupAlarm() >--------
        // AlarmManager instance from the system services
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)   this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Intent: this is responsible to prepare the android component what
       //PendingIntent will start when the alarm is triggered. That component 
       //can be anyone    (activity, service, broadcastReceiver, etc)
      // Intent to start the Broadcast Receiver
        Intent intent =new  Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        // PendingIntent: this is the pending intent, which waits until 
        //the right time, to be called by AlarmManager
        // The Pending Intent to pass in AlarmManager
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        //< create Alarm >
        setAlarm();
        //</ create Alarm >
        //--------</ setupAlarm() >--------
    }

    private void setAlarm() {
        //--------< setup() >--------
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) is.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+ 50000, endingIntent);
        //--------</ setup() >--------
    }
    //========</ Methods >===========
    //------------</ MainActivity >------------
 }
```

Creas ahora la página de Alarma:

```
public class PaginaAlarma extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pagina_alarma);
    }
}
```

XML Main Activity:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOpenWakeup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#A1A0A0"

    android:onClick="btnOpenWakeup"
    android:text="Open Wakeup"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnWakeup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#FFEB3B"
    android:onClick="btnAlarmSetWakeup"
    android:text="Alarm: Wakeup"
    android:textColor="#F44336"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnOpenWakeup" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

pagina XML de Alarma:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FF0000"
tools:context=".PaginaAlarma">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Alarm"
    android:textColor="#FFEB3B"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```